# Python program to store first N prime numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list, append, primes

I wrote the following code for finding N prime numbers. But,I have trouble       storing it in a list.

```
     def prime(n):

        global count
        s=0
        flag=0
        ls=[]
        for i in range(2,n/2+1):
                     if(n%i==0):
                           flag=1
                           break

        if(flag==0):
                print n
                ls.append(n)
                count=count+1
        print ls

    # main pro
    n=input("Enter the number of prime numbers to be displayed: ")
    print"The prime numbers are:"  
    count=0
    x=2
    while(count<n):
             prime(x)
             x+=1
```

My desired output should be:

```
    Enter the number of prime numbers to be displayed: 5
    [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
```

But when I run the program,I get output as:

```
    Enter the number of prime numbers to be displayed: 5
    The prime numbers are:
    2
    [2]
    3
    [3]
    []
    5
    [5]
    []
    7
    [7]
    []
    []
    []
    11
    [11]
```

How do I add prime numbers into a list without changing the above code??
Should I append the elements at a later part? I am new to Python,so all help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: declare `ls` globally, you're recreating it at each iteration.

Comment: But I am getting output as :
[2]
[2, 3]
[2, 3]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
How to print it once at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return array of `count` primes:

```
def get_primes(count):
    primes = []

    n = 2
    while len(primes) != count:
        for i in range(2, n // 2 + 1):
            if n % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(n)
        n += 1

    return primes
```

you can use it like so:

```
n=input("Enter the number of prime numbers to be displayed: ")
array_of_n_prime_numbers = get_primes(n)
print("The prime numbers are:", array_of_n_prime_numbers)
```

Comment: I understood that in above code, I had to declare list globally. 
 
But I am getting output as : [2] [2, 3] [2, 3] [2, 3, 5] [2, 3, 5] [2, 3, 5, 7] [2, 3, 5, 7] [2, 3, 5, 7] [2, 3, 5, 7] [2, 3, 5, 7, 11] How to print it once at the end? Thank you!

Comment: @AanandhiVB `print("The prime numbers are:", array_of_n_prime_numbers)`

Comment: @AanandhiVB you don't need to declare list globally

Comment: I am so sorry to confuse you, but according to Jean-François Fabre, when I declare list globally, I am able to get the prime number list. But I am getting output like :  [2] [2, 3] [2, 3] [2, 3, 5] [2, 3, 5] [2, 3, 5, 7] [2, 3, 5, 7] [2, 3, 5, 7] [2, 3, 5, 7] [2, 3, 5, 7, 11] How to print it once at the end?I don't want to change the code I wrote. Thankyou!

Comment: @AanandhiVB print it outside of your function then. You get this output because you print primes every time you call a function.

Comment: @AanandhiVB Why don't you try my solution. It does exactly what you want

Comment: Your code works really well! But I was wondering how to store them in a list in the code I wrote. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def prime(x):
    if x<1:
        return []
    prime_numbers = [2,3]
    if x<3:
        return prime_number[:x]
    for i in range(2,x):
        next_pn = prime_numbers[-1]+2
        while any(not(next_pn%pn) for pn in prime_numbers):
            next_pn += 2
        prime_numbers.append(next_pn)
    return prime_numbers

N = input("Enter the number of prime numbers to be displayed:")
print (prime(int(N)))
```

output

```
Enter the number of prime numbers to be displayed:5
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
```

need not iterate through all the numbers, instead you can iterate through only prime number before it.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: if it served your purpose accept the answer and upvote

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way:

```
def prime(n):
    ls = [2,3]
    if (n < 3):
        return ls[:n]
    for i in range(2,n):
        generate = ls[-1]+2
        while any(not(generate%num) for num in ls):
            generate += 2
        ls.append(generate)
    return ls



n = int(input("Enter the number of prime numbers to be displayed:"))
print (prime(n))
```

output when input is 5:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
```